# Automatic job naming in Quartz.NET

Tags: c#, quartz.net

Using Quartz.NET it seems like I need to name every job I create. Is there a way it can be automatically 'named', like an auto incrementing ID or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you use a `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` when you create your job? Thats what I have done in the past and it worked quite well

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just passing in the type name when you create the job.  Such as myObject.GetType().Name.